# Can Jenkins custom plugin on slave log to master?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Basicaly, I have exact the same question as linked here:
[How can i send data to the logger from FileCallable back to master in a Jenkins plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981459/how-can-i-send-data-to-the-logger-from-filecallable-back-to-master-in-a-jenkins)

but I can't get it to work. I have written my own custom Jenkins plugin and it has to run on a slave. I want to log, however, to the master jenkins (or at least to the build log). Here's my code (cut a bit for simplicity):

```
public class SanityTestResultsToJUnitXMLBuilder extends Builder implements Serializable  {

  // Some initialization code

  @Override
  public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) {   

    // Define what should be run on the slave for this build
    SlaveChannel slaveChannel = new SlaveChannel(sourceDirectories, destinationDirectory, listener.getLogger());
    if (launcher.getChannel().call(slaveChannel).equals("NOK")){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static final class SlaveChannel implements Callable<String, IOException>
  {
    // Again, some initialization code

    public SlaveChannel(String sourceDirectories, String destinationDirectory, PrintStream logger){
        this.sourceDirectories = sourceDirectories;
        this.destinationDirectory = destinationDirectory;
        this.logger = logger;           
    }

    public String call() throws UnknownHostException
    {
        logger.println("Running the SanityTestResultsToJUnitXML plugin on host: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        if (startProcess()){
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "NOK";
        }
    }

    private boolean startProcess(){
      // The code that needs to run client side
    }
  }
```

Right now it gives me the following output in Jenkins:
(And this is the master logging)

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize nl.tba.SanityTestResultsToJUnitXML.SanityTestResultsToJUnitXMLBuilder$SlaveChannel@7e2536bb
hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:166)
hudson.remoting.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:62)
hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:721)
nl.tba.SanityTestResultsToJUnitXML.SanityTestResultsToJUnitXMLBuilder.perform(SanityTestResultsToJUnitXMLBuilder.java:61)
hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:566)
hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Build step 'Execute SanityTestResultsToJUnitXML task' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So basicaly, the logger (which is a PrintStream) is not serializable. How do I still get my slave to log to the main Jenkins?

Comment: Is the problem *just* that you can't serialize an instance of `SlaveChannel`?  If you declare all the non-serializable fields as `transient` (so that they're not serialized) and re-create them whenever they're needed, what happens?

Comment: How about logging on the slave and copying the logs over to the master with the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin option?

Answer (score 1):

This should print to the build log:

```
listener.getLogger().println(your_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Listener object is serializable. So, you can pass this object to the callable class constructor, and use `listener.getLogger().println();` in the `call()` function.